# Changing colour of pin in MKmapView turns new pin image aswell as current location into old pin image?

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview, uicolor

Im trying to change the colour of one set of pins to blue and another set of pins to remain red. Ive followed a question on here that takes me to the point where the pins do change colour. But also my current location turns into a pin. Also the pins turn from the new logo, into the old logo (an actually image of a pin). Is there a way for the pins to remain like the new logo/image and also have my current location to be displayed as normal, i.e a blue pulsing dot. as well as changing one set of pins to blue while the rest remain red?

Please Help!
Below is my code:

```
class MyPointAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation {
var pinTintColor: UIColor?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet var map: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    map.delegate = self

    let anx = MyPointAnnotation()
    anx.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -36.56795, longitude: 176.56432)
    anx.pinTintColor = .red

    let any = MyPointAnnotation()
    any.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -36.54322, longitude: 176.43221)
    any.pinTintColor = .blue

    map.addAnnotation(anx)
    map.addAnnotation(any)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "myAnnotation") as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myAnnotation")
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    if let annotation = annotation as? MyPointAnnotation {
        annotationView?.pinTintColor = annotation.pinTintColor
    }

    return annotationView
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> But also my current location turns into a pin.

Add the following code in `mapView:viewFor...` method :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
```